# Itext 7.1.16 - adding Two Paragraphs dont work

Tags: java, itext7

i try to create PDF Document but i'am not able to Create a Document with 2 Paragraphs.
It just show the first one added:

[image]

Here is my code for reproducing:

```
public void createBillingDocument(List<PDFData> datas) {
        datas.forEach(data -> {
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream);
                PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
                Document document = new Document(pdf,PageSize.A4);
                document.add(new Paragraph("Muh"));
                document.add(new Paragraph("Kuh"));
                document.close();
                pdf.close();
                writer.close();
                outputStream.close();
                fileAccess.storeFile(outputStream.toString(), "test/" + "Name.pdf");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

Has anyone the same Problem an found a Solution?

Regards

Edit:
One Strange thing is, if i make a Breake betwenn it both Paragraphs are shown. Each one one Page.

```
try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream);
                PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
                Document document = new Document(pdf,PageSize.A4);
                document.add(new Paragraph("Muh"));
                document.add(new AreaBreak());
                document.add(new Paragraph("Kuh"));
                document.close();
                pdf.close();
                writer.close();
                outputStream.close();
                fileAccess.storeFile(outputStream.toString(), "test/" + "Name.pdf");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

Comment: could you delete the existing file and try again? might be a rewrite issue.

Comment: PDF files are binary data. Handling binary data as text is likely to damage the binary data. Thus, you should not store `outputStream.toString()` but instead `outputStream.toByteArray()`. I don't know your `fileAccess` object, so I cannot tell which method of it you can use for that if any.

Comment: @AbishekStephen Tried to delete the File but still same Issues, so iwould say no rewrite Issue.
The String i think is also not the Problem. file acces is just  a simple call to 'org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile'

Answer (score 2):

Ok found out. @mkl was right. The Problem lies somewhere in "save the Document as String". Chaged it to ByteArray and voila it worked :)
Thanks for your Time!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).